# Run Python script with arguments in Ansible

Tags: python, ansible

**I want to run a Python script from inside of an ansible playbook, with input arguments.** How do I do it?

I tried `command`, but it doesn't seem to take any input arguments.
I also tried `script`, but it seems to be considering only bash scripts.

PS: I am taking in the input arguments as `--extra-vars`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to run the script with the following statement:

```
- name: Run Py script
  command: /path/to/script/processing.py {{ N }} {{ bucket_name }}
  become: yes
  become_user: root
```

This solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

No, `script` module is for all type of scripts

you have to give `#!/usr/bin/python` at very first line in your python script file.

```
# Example from Ansible Playbooks
- script: /some/local/script.py 1234
```

Python file example :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.'
print '1st Argument :', str(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Thanks,  But, it is giving me this error: http://pastebin.com/xZdAqbNu

I did this: `- name: Run Python Script
      script: /home/ec2-user/AnsibleDir/GitRepo/processing.py --some-arguments N, bucket_name`

Comment: I did attach the link to pastebin of the error in the above comment.  Anyways, here it is: http://pastebin.com/xZdAqbNu

Comment: how you are catching those arguments???? in script???   i mean using sys.argv???????

Comment: Yes.  With sys.argv.  `N = sys.argv[1]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134758/discussion-between-dawny33-and-jameel-grand).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding

> *I want to run a Python script from inside of an Ansible playbook, with input arguments. ... I tried `command`, but it doesn't seem to take any input arguments.*

and technically, the `command` module itself, as well inline code [can just be used with facts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42201102/6771046) and therefore `--extra-vars`.

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Python inline code example
    command: /usr/bin/python
    args:
      stdin: |
        import glob
        print(glob.glob("/home/{{ ansible_user }}/*"))
    register: results

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ results.stdout }}"
```

... even if that (inline code) is not a recommended way to use Ansible and his capabilities.